# Stewardship of the byobu tag

Tags: discussion, support

A friend of mine writes [Byobu](http://launchpad.net/byobu) and prefers to use stackexchanges rather than the [Launchpad Answers](https://answers.launchpad.net/byobu) feature. However there are 77 questions worth of decent content there. He'd like to move over to using a stackexchange and superuser seemed to be the best fit.

I wanted to post this on meta because we wanted to make sure we did this the [right way](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/stack-overflow-flash-mobs/) instead of a way that is [less than ideal](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/2314/synergy-specific-entry-page) and to get feedback.

So far here's my plan:

- Weed through the existing questions, post the ones that are still relevant on superuser, updated if necessary.
- The author is subscribed to the tag and will take ownership of it by answering questions.

This project is relatively small so I don't think it's going to be a big problem. Did I miss anything?

Comment: +1, I'm on board, Jorge.  I'd love to use superuser for byobu questions and answers!

Comment: One thing you need to make sure is that his users will understand how this site works. There will be no leniency in case of bad, subjective etc. questions. If there's some customisation possible and someone asks for the best, favourite option it *will* get closed. It's just not a discussion board.

Comment: @DanielBeck You probably meant „It’s not _just_ a discussion board”

Comment: @kinokijuf No, I didn't. We don't generally discuss things. We ask and answer questions. This site is not suited for extended discussions. Posts aren't necessarily sorted by date, and comments are second class citizens. We don't tolerate stupid or content-free posts.

Comment: According to our [about](http://superuser.com/about) page, we are both a forum, wiki, blog and a digg/reddit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As long as its meant as a tool for user questions (like how it works) and not developer questions or feature requests, then I don't see a problem if he decides to migrate relevant questions to Super User.

I would advise to do so in a somewhat organic fashion, so his questions don't flood the front page, but given the work involved with asking and answering 77 questions, I'm sure he won't even try doing it in one go.

Given that the developer is on top of it, I'm sure we'll be able to deal with any problems **if** they occur. So I'm not worried about getting flooded by feature requests and the like.

Comment: Ok I'll trickle in a few at a time and watch this question for feedback, thanks!

Comment: Do make sure that the developer mentions in his profile that he's affiliated with the project, too, as per our affiliation requirements.